# Separate a curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have 2 objects that look like they are grouped or linked somehow but I'm not sure how to separate them?

[image: desk]

In the box in the top right, you see 'Curve 037', I want to take out 'Curve 036' underneath and then delete 37.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like curve 036 is parented to curve 037.  Select the 036 curve in the 3D window and press ALT-P.  Click on "Clear Parent". The two curves will be independent again.

Comment: That done it, thank you. I tried it before but I must of been selecting the wrong object to separate. Cheers!